# Landline number validation in Android

Tags: android

In my application there is a field called Land Line number, I want to restrict the user not to enter all zeros like "0000000000" but he can enter like "0123467889"."0801234567","98001245780"
Starting zero and iin any position zero is acceptable, but not all zeros

Comment: Can you share any code with us?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15644461/1134197

Comment: You can write a regular expression to check if your specific pattern has been matched. There is Pattern class that provides the following method, boolean matches (String regex, 
                CharSequence input)

Comment: public static final boolean isValPhoneNumberLand(CharSequence target) {

        String regex = "[0123456789]{1}\\d{9}";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        boolean matcher;
        matcher = pattern.matcher(target).matches();
        return matcher;
}

Comment: The above method i am using to validate, but it is accepting all zeros

Comment: your regex isn't correct. Check the answer.

Comment: can u suggest me a regexp which suits my requirement

Answer (score 0):

This should do it,

```
private boolean isNumberValid(String number){
    return Pattern.matches("^[0-9][1-9]{9}$", number);
}
```

Comment: it is not allowing all zeros, its fine, but it is not allowing zero any place of 10 digit num, 
My requirement is, not to allow all zeros
But it can accept a ph num like 0801234567 etc.,

Comment: I dont think a regex alone can fulfill this requirement then. You need something like this stackoverflow.com/a/15644461/1134197.

Comment: Try this as well, android.util.Patterns.PHONE.matcher(number).matches();